Neither as a determiner
Which one of following sentences is right?

Digital version of the document is not accessible neither through the web repository nor through the company archive.

Digital version of the document is accessible neither through the web repository nor through the company digital repository.



I don't find your first example idiomatic, because you've already negated the first of the "neither / nor" pair with not accessible - which to my ear means it's a "double negation" on a par with "Please check I haven't made no mistakes here".

In addition to @FumbleFingers’s comment, FYI, both your sentences cry out for articles, either A digital version or The digital version.

...as for the second, I don't like your position of "neither", but at least that's a stylistic choice. You do need an initial article, though, so I'd prefer The / A 2-digital version of the document is neither accessible through the web repository nor through the company digital repository. That's if you insist on using "neither / nor", which I'm not convinced is the best stylistic choice in this exact context anyway.

That is not neither as a determiner. This is. but it requires previous context: Neither boy passed the exam.

The dictionary answers this: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either_2

Neither means, essentially, “not either,” so your sentence 1 is not idiomatic. Here is a pair of negative uses that are idiomatic:

I was neither pleased nor surprised by the news
Chocolate should not be fed to dogs, either domestic or feral.


A digital version ... is not accessible through either the ... web.... or the archive.
To say that it is accessible neither ... nor ... , when it is not accessible in any way, is to invite confusion. People are human, not machines, and so you have to write defensively, assuming that people are easily confused.
Better to say "not accessible ... either ... or...." when your sentence does not offer any way to access.

Here is neither used as a determiner:
Neither boy came to the party.
And here, as a conjunction:
**Neither the boy nor his mother came to the party. [correlative conjunction: declarative sentence]
Here is neither/nor and either/or as a correlative conjunction:
NEGATIVE SENTENCE

A digital version of the document is not accessible either through the web repository or through the company archive.

DECLARATIVE SENTENCE
2) A digital version of the document is accessible neither through the web repository nor the company archive.
A negative sentence uses either/or.
A declarative uses neither/nor.
Sentence 1) would be more likely in an IT context like that.
